# Why is my POST file_get_contents returning HTTP Bad Request?

Tags: php, rest, post, curl, file-get-contents

Here's my code:

```
$url = 'http://99.99.99.999:12480/rs/AuthorizationSession';
$credentials = 'admin:system';
$base64 = base64_encode($credentials);

// Set header text.
$header =   "Content-type: application/json\r\n" .
            "Accept: application/json\r\n" .
            "RESTAuthorization: " . $base64;

// Set data.
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        "authorization" => $base64
    )
);

// Set options - POST.
$opts = array("http" => 
    array(
        "method" => "POST",
        "header" => $header,
        "content" => $postdata
    )
);

// Create context and execute.
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

I keep getting: `file_get_contents(http://99.99.99.999:12480/rs/AuthorizationSession): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`

Obviously I changed the IP. This works for a GET request but not POST.

I figure I must have something wrong with my header or post data, but I can't figure it out.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/http_build_query) converts an array to a URL-encoded query string like `name=john&password=s3cr3t` but the `Content-Type` header you are sending says the POST data is in JSON.

The request either needs to be changed to reflect the correct Content-Type (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, or `http_build_query` should really be [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) to send the data as JSON.

As it stands now, the server is confused that you are telling it you're sending JSON, but instead sending a URL encoded string (so essentially JSON parsing on the remote is failing) and generating a bad request.

Comment: Hmm, using that content-type results in: `HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type`.

Comment: Is there documentation saying what type of POST to be doing?  If they are expecting JSON, your Content-Type header in the OP is correct, but you should use json_encode instead of http_build_query.  As it stands now your actual data doesn't match the content-type, but it appears to not be wanting the standard application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: Yes, they are expecting JSON, and you are absolutely correct that I should be using json_encode and it now works. I hadn't looked properly into http_build_query and made some assumptions! Poor move on my part.

Comment: Awesome, glad that was it.  Updating the answer now to reflect the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your code works with GET, but POST fails, it sounds like the host located at 99.99.99.999:12480 on the target server may not be configured to accept POST requests.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that the provider I'm working with is successfully able to POST to the server using their own functionality. (Not PHP.)